# Complexity of Lists in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, complexity-theory

Is a List in C# equal to that of an ArrayList in terms of time complexity?

As it is my understanding that they're both similar in how they function, being dynamic arrays?

Comment: I think, yes, you can assume it. But What is your real question, what do you want to measure?

Comment: Whether a List has equal time complexities compared to an ArrayList in terms of insertion, deletion, searching, etc!

Comment: You can read the documentation for both types to see what they each do, how they differ, how they are implemented, etc.

Comment: I believe there's no significant performance difference, but the primary difference is that `List` is generic.

Comment: And if the documentation is not enough you can read the source for both [ArrayList](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#3e3f6715773d6643) and [List](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#cf7f4095e4de7646) too

Comment: I've tried to do some research into it, it's still ambiguous to me whether the time complexities of each data structure would differ based upon the fact that Lists are generic and ArrayLists aren't? I don't see any time complexity change just because of this difference!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "time complexities", but for value types, updating values in a generic list can be faster because there will be no boxing / unboxing.

Comment: @Bradley  There's an *entire section* of the documentation explaining the performance differences of these types in great detail.

Comment: @Joe That will have no effect on the asymptotic complexity of the operations; the boxing is a constant-time increase in the run time.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I'll take a look and see if I can find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `ArrayList` and `List<T>` have the same basic implementation, using an array to store the items, reallocating as necessary when items are added. Indeed, much of `List<T>` is simply copy/paste from `ArrayList`, with appropriate changes to support the generics.

While there may be small differences in actual performance, the "big-O" complexity of operations in each would be the same.